# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object on trigger

Tags: apex

I am trying to call a method from a trigger that will generate a pdf whenever any order(object) record is created. I wrote a after insert, after updated trigger and called the method for pdf generation like below.

```
  for (Order_vod__c ord : trigger.new)
  {
      if (ord != null)
      {
           PDFExport_OrderDetails exp= new  PDFExport_OrderDetails();
          exp.send_order_pdf(ord.id);
      }
  }


  //method body
  public PageReference send_order_pdf(Id ordId)
  {
      List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
      String orderId ;
      if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') != null)
      {
        orderId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');  
      }
      Order_vod__c order =[SELECT Id,Name,Owner.Email,Account_vod__r. Email__c From Order_vod__c WHERE Id=:orderId ];
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
      PageReference pdf;
      pdf = new PageReference('/apex/View_Order_vod?id='+orderId);
      pdf.getParameters().put('id',orderId); 
      pdf.setRedirect(true);
      Blob b = pdf.getContent(); 
      System.debug('Blob ****'+b);

      Messaging.EmailFileAttachment fileAttachmt = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
      fileAttachmt.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
      fileAttachmt.setBody(b);
      System.debug('fileAttachmt****'+fileAttachmt);
      String address ;

     if(order.Owner.Email!= null)
     {
        address= order.Owner.Email;
     }
     //String[] toAddress=address.split(',',0);
     System.debug('Rep email id****'+address);
     toAddress.add(address);
     toAddress.add('abc@xyz.com');
     email.setToAddresses(toAddress);
     System.debug('email*****'+email);
     email.setPlainTextBody('Please find the Order'+order.Name+' as an attachment');
     email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {fileAttachmt});
     // Sends the email
     Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});    
     return null;
 }
```

but I am getting an error "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object".
Although I kept the checking ord != null, not sure what is causing this error. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Where are you getting the `null` dereference? What debug output are you seeing? `ord` is never going to be `null` as the trigger wouldn't process a null record reference.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing parameter `ordId` to the method `send_order_pdf()` and not using it.
you are using `orderId` in the query. 
 That is giving you null order  and you might be getting  `NullPointerException` at line `if(order.Owner.Email!= null)` because you are trying to access owner of null.

Comment: hi, corrceted that. Now I am getting the same error on ----if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') != null)

Comment: You can change your approach. Just get the id in the constructor and pass that id to your method so its behavior remains same in both cases ( i.e. called from trigger or from vf page)

Comment: Hi Sven- I used the below lines in constructor only ------ public PFE_PDFExport_OrderDetails() 
    {              
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') != null)
        {
            oId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');  
            System.debug('**** ORDER ID **** '+oId); and getting error on - " oId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');  "

Comment: is old declared as instance variable?

Comment: can you post separate question for that with error msg?